# Android aChartengine - How to fill color above the reference line in Green and below reference line in Magenta

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I have used aChartEngine
This is my code for my lineChart

```
XYSeriesRenderer xyRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);
XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine fill; XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_BELOW);
fill.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
xyRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

The lineChart should colored in magenta for every area that is below the green line. However, as you can see that aChartengine render only the first area.
So what have I missed?
I also found that when I move the chart (shown in the figure 2) the chart will render only the first area. The figure 3 the chart render 2 areas.
the figure 4 show the result of the code below.

```
    fill = new XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
fill.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
xyRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);

fill = new XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ABOVE);
fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
xyRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

[image: aChartEngine problems with color bounded below the line chart]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL` instead of `FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_BELOW`.

Comment: No the FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL properties will also color the area ablow the zero in magenta too I just want magenta only the area below the zero

Comment: Add one fill behavior for BOUNDS_BELOW and another one for BOUNDS_ABOVE.

Comment: I have tried that way but still bug as show in figure 4 that I just uploaded.

Comment: I have the same bug - and I added the ability to set the bound to something other than the origin - but I need specifically BOUNDS_BELOW, although BOUNDS_ALL does fix the bug. I'm writing my bug report up now.

Comment: and I have another putative fix for this bug here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728106/achartengine-bug-in-addfilloutsideline-where-the-fill-overflows-the-line